# Java Drag and Drop issues in socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, drag-and-drop

I have been trying to develop a software using java sockets and before using Drag and Drop, my code was working just the way I wanted it to. However, after combining it with drag and drop, I am getting quite unexpected results. Following is some code snippets of the server class of my code.

```
    public ServerFirstPage() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    try {     
        System.out.println("in the try block");
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3389);
                server = ss.accept();
                   // new generatePassword(server);

                    } catch (IOException ex) {

   Logger.getLogger(ServerFirstPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ServerFirstPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ServerFirstPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ServerFirstPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ServerFirstPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

             new ServerFirstPage().setVisible(true);
             System.out.println("entered");
        }
    });
}
```

Firstly I should mention that the code in the main class and in the constructor were generated by Netbeans.
My problem is that, when I comment out the try-catch block in the ServerFirstPage() and then run my code, the GUI portion of my code gets displayed on my screen. But when I do not comment out that part, my code shows nothing in the screen and since my code won't work if I leave out the try-catch part, as it is where my server gets connected to the client, I am not sure what to do or how to solve the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a fully executable code? In your example, the `initComponents()` is not declared, we do not know the superclass of `ServerFirstPage` (probably JFrame) and there is nothing mentioned about the DnD implementation. Additionall, can you describe what you want to achieve with this program? We can not read your thoughs.

Comment: @The_Proggrammer
initComponents() has been declared by NetBeans as well. It just initiates the components of the GUI.
I am trying to make a software similar to  Teamviewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your socket server is waiting for a connection. That code should run on a different thread than the event dispatch thread. Look at what your code is doing and reorganize it.

Comment: Yes the GUI appears after I have connected the server with the client. Thanks for your help. Could you explain it to me why though? The main class is supposed to run before anything else and it sets the visibility of the page to true. So why does the GUI appear after the client and the socket gets connected?